# Matrix factorization methods in recommendation systems

Tags: matrix, machine-learning, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I was doing a bit of reading with respect to matrix factorization methods in recommendation systems and came across this really nice tutorial: http://www.quuxlabs.com/blog/2010/09/matrix-factorization-a-simple-tutorial-and-implementation-in-python/

Everything was good, but this paragraph had me intrigued:

> A question might have come to your mind by now: if we find two matrices **P** and **Q** such that **PXQ** approximates **R,** isn’t that our predictions of all the unseen ratings will all be zeros? In fact, we are not really trying to come up with P and Q such that we can reproduce R exactly. Instead, we will only try to minimise the errors of the observed user-item pairs. In other words, if we let **T** be a set of tuples, each of which is in the form of **(u_i, d_j, r_ij)**, such that T contains all the observed user-item pairs together with the associated ratings, we are only trying to minimise every **e_ij** for (u_i, d_j, r_ij) in T. (In other words, T is our set of training data.) As for the rest of the unknowns, we will be able to determine their values once the associations between the users, items and features have been learnt.

I was wondering if someone could help me with this? Do latent factors help us in understanding the behavior of each user and item?

Thanks

Comment: What is exactly your question? Can you clarify?

Comment: How do latent factors help identify the unknown quantities? I could take out a certain number number of user-item pairings, and make that as a test set. I could train on the rest. How would my algorithm predict values in the test set that were zero in the training set?

Comment: If i am understanding things correctly, my predictions matrix is generated out of my training set. It would have larger values for non zero values in my training set. How can that same predictions matrix be used for my test set?

Comment: tried to explain it, if there's still something you don't get let me know.

Comment: Thanks @JoãoAlmeida . So, if I create my test set with one non zero value from (every row of) the training set and keep everything else as zero. I should be able to recommend that item, using my predictions matrix created from the training set. Am i correct?

Comment: Something of this sort: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650664/generating-test-set-for-recommendation-engine

Comment: Yes. You should also set that rating to zero on your training set, so that you don't overfit the data.

Comment: If you have more questions you should check: [Section 9.4 of Mining Massive Datasets](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch9.pdf).

Comment: Yes, they helps - if having great amount of factors/features described - while transformating feature-space you factorize data to the space, that mostly explains the variance, while taking into consideration weight of each feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latent factors are two set of values (a set for the users and a set for the items) that describe the user and the item. Essentially what you are trying to do is to find a numerical representation of your items and users.

Imagine that you have movie rating system and have 3 factors for users and 3 factors for movies (items). The user items can be how much you like comedies, drama or action movies and the movie factors how much of a comedy, drama or action movie it is. From these properties you could estimate the ratings of other pairs. This model finds these abstract factors for you.

This means that **you can only find a reasonable representation for items and users for which you have ratings**. 
So when you train your model you use the known ratings to estimate this representation. From it you can try to predict an unknown rating of a user and item.

Comment: [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/prototyping-a-recommender-system-step-by-step-part-2-alternating-least-square-als-matrix-4a76c58714a1) "*cold-start-problem*" (absence of new product's info) is suggested to solve with PCA's SVD  algorithm to extract **latent-factors**, & ALS algorithm implementing Matrix Factorization, that runs itself in a parallel fashion (libs spark, implicit, [tensorflow](https://github.com/KevinLiao159/MyDataSciencePortfolio/blob/master/movie_recommender/src/neural_recommender.py), that is told to improve recomendations done with KNN for Collaborative filtering

Comment: [Alternating Least Squares With Weighted Regularization](https://ethen8181.github.io/machine-learning/recsys/1_ALSWR.html)

Comment: or [The essence of Alternating Least Square](https://towardsdatascience.com/alternating-least-square-for-implicit-dataset-with-code-8e7999277f4b)

Comment: concerning "only find a reasonable representation for items and users for which you have ratings" - only if using [simple KNN](https://github.com/jisilvia/kNN_Recommender_System/blob/main/kNN_Recommender_System.ipynb), but it is always possible to find some correlations among other available features, (not only rates given by users as in the example) - for this purpose PCA , PLS are used